# CSS Nth child selector - style

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<a class="abc">
     <span class="def">foo</span>
     bar
   </a>
```

How do I target the bar to make it bold - i can not give any css class to it, tried nth child but did not work - tried out nth child like this: but did not work - tested on ff.

```
abc a:nth-child(2) {
text-weight:bold !important;
}
```

Comment: can u not give .abc bold and def normal?

Comment: It's `.abc` not `abc` and it's `font-weight` not `text-weight`.

Comment: this is not a good way to use nth-child css u can see below in my example

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with the css rules. write it as

```
   .abc a:nth-child(2) {
    font-weight:bold !important;
    }
```

and to achieve the affect you want, change your css as

```
    a.abc {
    font-weight:bold!important;
    }
.def{
    font-weight:normal!important;
    }


​
```

**[See JsFiddle Demo for later](http://jsfiddle.net/96e32/9/)**

Comment: have you try this?it is not working in Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/96e32/4/

Comment: your code working fine just for `span` text (i.e. foo), but in Question, he try to bold out text `bar` , and your code not working for text `bar`, i updated your fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/96e32/7/

Answer (score 0):

you can do a trick to do this.

```
.abc
{
  font-weight:bold;
}
.def{

font-weight:normal;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="abc">
     <span class="def">foo</span>
     bar
</a>
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/96e32/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the bar text in span coz when you targeting by nth-child css you have to show same tags i've create both examples check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/ShRnY/

and also use this below code

```
.abc :nth-child(2) {
    font-weight:bold;
}

<a class="abc">
     <span class="def">foo</span>
     <span>bar</span>
   </a>​
```

Answer (score -1):

**Now try this**

```
.abc:nth-child(2) {
font-weight:bold !important;
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FpXh6/)***